# Laravel - How to add extra column to Laravel Spatie Permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

In my Laravel-8 project, I am using Spatie-Permission. I want to add extra column, company_id to the Spatie Role table. In the migration, I did this:

```
php artisan make:migration add_company_column_to_role_tables
```

Also, in the config/permission:

```
    //'permission' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission::class,
    'permission' => App\Models\Permission::class,

    //'role' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::class,
    'role' => App\Models\Role::class,
```

I want each company to create its roles, but the permissions remain the same.
What else do I need to do in order to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you have also run the migration? Once you've run the migration and the field is added to the database table, you'll need to update your methods of creating roles to associated a company with a role.

Comment: @Peppermintology - I'm asking this because Spatie-Permission is a package and I on't know if there are some other things I need to know

Comment: My previous comment provides some direction. You'll also want to consider the relationships between a `Role` and `Company` and how to scope `Role` queries to a `Company`.

Comment: @Peppermintology - How do I scope Role Queries to a Company?

Comment: Have a look at some tutorials such as [this one](https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-8-query-scope-example/) and [this one](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch).

Answer (score 0):

I recently face this. I needed to have an additional **display_name** for my permissions. People on the spatie github repo said it was better to use Laravel translations in the next fashion:

```
__('your string permission')
```

But I found that not that suitable. So I did this:

1. Added a migration: `php artisan make:migration addCustomColumnsToPermissionsTable`
2. Then, added the following:

   ```
   public function up() {
       Schema::table('permissions', function (Blueprint $table){
           $table->string('display_name')->after('name');
       });
   }
   public function down() {
       Schema::table('permissions', function (Blueprint $table){
           $table->dropColumn('display_name');
       });
   }
   ```

3.- finally run: `php artisan migrate`

And voila! you have your new column. Hope that helps :D